# Google Maps API - FusionTables Layer Example - Map not being displayed

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying the Google Maps API Advanced Visualization example with my data.  However, neither the map nor the chart are being displayed. The debugger on Chrome listed the error as:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "offsetWidth" as null.

I read the responses to that specific error here at Stack and also in the old google groups, but none of the suggestions worked for me.

I was hoping someone can take a look at the code and let me know what I am missing. I am pretty sure it is something very small, but I've hit a wall and so hoping for another set of eyes on this.

Please note that this is the exact version of the example code - tweaked slightly for my dataset to able to check it out.

Thanks in advance.
Code is below.

### -Madhavi

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });

      /** * Sector type mapped to a style rule. * @type {Object} * @const */ var LAYER_STYLES = { 'Operational': { 'min': 0, 'max': 10000, 'colors': [ '#f4cccc', '#ea9999', '#e06666', '#cc0000',
       '#990000' ] }, 'Formally Approved': { 'min': 0, 'max': 10000, 'colors': [ '#d0e0e3', '#a2c4c9', '#76a5af', '#45818e', '#134f5c' ] }, 'In-Principle Approved': { 'min': 0, 'max': 20000, 'colors': [
       '#d9d2e9', '#b4a7d6', '#8e7cc3', '#674ea7', '#351c75' ] } }

function initialize() {

  var sector = 'Operational';

  var india = new google.maps.LatLng(21.7679,78.8718); var options = {}; options['dataMode'] = 'markers';

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), { center: india, zoom: 5, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, zoomControlOptions: { style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL },
    });

  var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(); updateLayerQuery(layer, sector); layer.setMap(map);

  createLegend(map,sector); styleLayerBySector(layer,sector); styleMap(map); drawVisualization('Andhra Pradesh');

  google.maps.event.addListener(layer,'click',function(e) { var state = e.row['State'].value; drawVisualization(state);

  var area = e.row['Area in Acres'].value; if (area > 5000) { e.infoWindowHtml = '<p class="high">High SEZ area!</p>'; } else if (area > 2500) { e.infoWindowHtml = '<p class="high">Medium SEZ area!</p>
  '; } else { e.infoWindowHtml = '<p class="high">Low SEZ area!</p>'; }

 });

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('sector'), 'change',function() { sector = this.value; updateLayerQuery(layer,sector); styleLayerBySector(layer,sector); updateLegend(sector);
    });

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('state'), 'change',function() { var state = this.value; updateLayerQuery(layer,sector,state); drawVisualization(state); }); };

function updateLayerQuery(layer,sector,state) { var where = "SEZ Type= '"+ sector + "'"; if (state) { where += "AND State = '" + state + "'"; } layer.setOptions({ query: { select : 'geometry', from:
    '4070871', where: where } }); }

function createLegend(map, sector) { var legendWrapper = document.createElement('div'); legendWrapper.id = 'legendWrapper'; legendWrapper.index = 1;
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM].push( legendWrapper); legendContent(legendWrapper, sector); }

function legendContent(legendWrapper, sector) { var legend = document.createElement('div'); legend.id = 'legend';

        var title = document.createElement('p'); title.innerHTML = sector + ' SEZs by State in India'; legend.appendChild(title);

        var layerStyle = LAYER_STYLES[sector]; var colors = layerStyle.colors; var minNum = layerStyle.min; var maxNum = layerStyle.max; var step = (maxNum - minNum) / colors.length; for (var i = 0; i <
        colors.length; i++) { var legendItem = document.createElement('div');

          var color = document.createElement('div'); color.setAttribute('class', 'color'); color.style.backgroundColor = colors[i]; legendItem.appendChild(color);

          var newMin = minNum + step * i; var newMax = newMin + step; var minMax = document.createElement('span'); minMax.innerHTML = newMin + ' - ' + newMax; legendItem.appendChild(minMax);

          legend.appendChild(legendItem); }

        legendWrapper.appendChild(legend); }

   function updateLegend(sector) { var legendWrapper = document.getElementById('legendWrapper'); var legend = document.getElementById('legend'); legendWrapper.removeChild(legend); legendContent(
          legendWrapper, sector); }

    function styleLayerBySector(layer, sector) { var layerStyle = LAYER_STYLES[sector]; var colors = layerStyle.colors; var minNum = layerStyle.min; var maxNum = layerStyle.max; var step = (maxNum -
            minNum) / colors.length;

            var styles = new Array(); for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) { var newMin = minNum + step * i; styles.push({ where: generateWhere(newMin, sector), polygonOptions: { fillColor:
            colors[i], fillOpacity: 1 } }); } layer.set('styles', styles); }

function generateWhere(minNum, sector) { var whereClause = new Array(); whereClause.push("Sector = '"); whereClause.push(sector); whereClause.push("' AND 'Area in Acres' >= "); whereClause.push(minNum);
        return whereClause.join(''); }

 function styleMap(map) { var style = [{ featureType: 'all', stylers: [{ saturation: -99 }] }, { featureType: 'poi', stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }] }, { featureType: 'road', stylers: [{ visibility:
        'off' }] }];

        var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(style, { map: map, name: 'Styled Map' }); map.mapTypes.set('map-style', styledMapType); map.setMapTypeId('map-style'); }

function drawVisualization(state) { google.visualization.drawChart({ containerId: "visualization", dataSourceUrl: "http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=", query: "SELECT 'SEZ Type' as Sector,
        'Area in Acres' as Area " + "FROM 4070871 WHERE State = '" + state + "'", chartType: "ColumnChart", options: { title: state, height: 400, width: 400 } }); }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize()); </script> </head> <body >

     <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 500px;height: 500px">Loading..</div> <div id="visualization"></div> <form> <label>SEZ Type </label> <select id="sector"> <option value="Operational">Operational
     </option> <option value="Formally Approved">Formally Approved</option> <option value="In-Principle Approved">In-Principle Approved</option> </select>

 <label>State</label> <select id="state"> <option value="Andhra Pradesh">Andhra Pradesh</option> <option value="Chandigarh">Chandigarh</option> <option value="Chattisgarh">Chattisgarh</option> <option
  value="Dadra and Nagar Haveli">Dadra and Nagar Haveli</option> <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>

  </select> </form> </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify the size of your div that holds a map.

Further make sure that your map variable is defined in global scope and make sure you do initialize the map when dom loaded i.e. on body load

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I tried all that you suggested(adding DIV size and moving map var declaration to the global scope) and still no effect. In fact, I realised that the original code example found here does not work either when deployed locally either. The map does not show up and I see the exact same error message in Chrome. does not work either. I added the DIV size to this code as well locally and no change. Any other ideas? Anything else I can do to fix this? This is really frustrating since I am stuck here for 2 days now.